# [react-native]Invalid prop `height` supplied to `View`

Tags: android, react-native

I have a view:

```
<View style={{height:this.state.pan.y}}></View>
```

with init state:

```
  ...
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {pan:new Animated.ValueXY()};
  }
  ...
```

it throws the error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `height` supplied to `View`.
Bad object: {
  "height": 0
}
```

but if i set:

```
<View style={{height:0}}></View>
```

it works ,why?

Answer (score 7):

sorry ,my mistake, I should use `Animated.View` tag, not View.

Answer (score 2):

i have trying your code, and i think `this.state.pan.y` have `object` propTypes like this :

```
{ 
_children: [],
_value: 0,
_startingValue: 0,
_offset: 0,
_animation: null,
_listeners: {} 
}
```

you can `console.log(this.state.pan.y)` to see that.
if you want to set `height` of your view using `value` of `y` you can change this one :

```
<View style={{height:this.state.pan.y}}></View>
```

to this one :

```
<View style={{height:this.state.pan.y._value}}></View>
```

i have trying that code and works, hope it can solve your problem, thanks :)

Note : thats not recommended access private object (underscore)

Comment: thanks, you are right, but the same code on translateY,it works.

Comment: For anyone who experiences this in the future: the real solution *is to use an animatable view if you're using `Animated`* -- `<Animated.View style={...}></Animated.View>`.

Answer (score 0):

`AnimatedXY()` values are not numbers but `Animated.Value` objects. In your case, you can access it directly with `_value` property, but it's not recommended (where underscore is a symbol of private member).

But I'd recommend going with separate `Animated.Value()` for height and manipulating that one.